# SQL query with group by and where filtering a received parameter

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do in Linq EF this my sql query:

```
SELECT date FROM tab_4009_atv
WHERE id_asset IN ['ako','bj89','flity76']
GROUP BY date;
```

but there's a specific situation.
This list that I'm filtering is received as a parameter like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable< Date>> getDates (IEnumerable< string>assetList){ }.
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query and the C# method signature you have given don't really fit each other. SQL query returns a grouping of dates, but the C# method returns a list of dates. We need to modify the return type of the method.

On the other hand, this question is more about converting the string to the `Asset` object than SQL or LINQ. Since we do not know what the `Asset` object looks like we cannot help you with that conversion. We have to delegate that responsibility to another method.

Additionally, the method doesn't need to be async.

The following code should do what you are looking for.

```cs
public class Asset
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string? OtherData { get; set; }
}

private static Asset StringToDate(string assetString)
{
    // Convert string to asset object
}

public IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, Asset>> GetDates(IEnumerable<string> assetList)
{
    var filter = new[] {"ako", "bj89", "flity76"};
    
    var dates = assetList
        .Where(x => filter.Contains(x))
        .Select(x => StringToDate(x))
        .GroupBy(assets => assets.Date);

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: assetList is a list of strings that represents a register in my db, but i received as a parameter
my 'id_asset', and 'date' in query belongs to a table in db.

my method must return a list of dates based on the assetList that i'm passing..

because the dates are not in assets, they are in my database table.

i think its almost this linq but i dont understand how the code is querying that date in db..

Comment: @RafaelMartins I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Give the explicit goal and desired input and output formats. Only then might I be able to help you. Do you want to translate the SQL query to C#? What does your relational data look like? What will be the output?

Comment: yes, translate to c# the sql clause WHERE IN but comparing with a list of string parameter. 
goal is to make just 1 hit in database and search all elements in this list instead doing one hit to each element of that list that makes more hits in database.....

better? rs the other problem is that i only have access to the code in my week job